# how to show internet connection on and off for globally in application in android?

Tags: android

1. I have shown custom dialog on broadcast recieve
2. and remove on internet off automaticlly

> But i want to implement it (without adding in all activities) i want to make it common so
>   no need to add it on each activity

**i recieve though this method through interface**

```
@Override
    public void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected) {
        showSnack(isConnected);
    }


private void showSnack(boolean isConnected) {

        if (isConnected) {
            customDialogClass.cancel();
        } else {
            customDialogClass.show();
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use base class(Activity) for your Dialog show/hide and extend all the activity to base class(Activity).

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to create a **AbstractActivity** which should extend **AppCompatActivity**. In abstract activity under **onResume()** method register a broadcast receiver  for to get internet connection status and **onDestroy()** method unregister the receiver.

After doing this now extend every activity with **AbstractActivity** which you have created.

Under **onReceive()** method of broadcast receiver you can put your own logic to show dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below method for checking the internet connectivity. It will return null if an internet connection is not available.

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

You will also need:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

in your android manifest.

Comment: Thanks for answer but its all working as you see in my output, i want to do it at one place (like i don't want to add in every activity)

Comment: i think for that you can use any github library for checking an internet connection.

Comment: please refer if you know any

Answer (score 0):

```
//network check
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Activity activity) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but its all working as you see in my output, i want to do it at one place (like i don't want to add in every activity)

Comment: i dont know how it will help

Comment: this is an android

Answer (score 0):

**1. Create a class named ConnectivityReceiver.java and extend it from BroadcastReceiver.**

```
    public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 
    public static ConnectivityReceiverListener connectivityReceiverListener;
 
    public ConnectivityReceiver() {
        super();
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null
                && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
 
        if (connectivityReceiverListener != null) {
            connectivityReceiverListener.onNetworkConnectionChanged(isConnected);
        }
    }
 
    public static boolean isConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager
                cm = (ConnectivityManager) MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetwork != null
                && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
 
 
    public interface ConnectivityReceiverListener {
        void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected);
    }}
```

**2. Create another class named MyApplication.java and extend it from Application.**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
 
    private static MyApplication mInstance;
 
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
 
        mInstance = this;
    }
 
    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }
 
    public void setConnectivityListener(ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener listener) {
        ConnectivityReceiver.connectivityReceiverListener = listener;
    }
}
```

**3.Open AndroidManifest.xml and do the below changes.**

> Add MyApplication to  tag.
>
> Add ConnectivityReceiver as .
>
> Declare INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permissions.

```
 <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <receiver
        android:name=".ConnectivityReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**4.MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener {
 
    private Button btnCheck;
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 
        btnCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_check);
 
        // Manually checking internet connection
        checkConnection();
 
        btnCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Manually checking internet connection
                checkConnection();
            }
        });
    }
 
    // Method to manually check connection status
    private void checkConnection() {
        boolean isConnected = ConnectivityReceiver.isConnected();
        showSnack(isConnected);
    }
 
    // Showing the status in Snackbar
    private void showSnack(boolean isConnected) {
        String message;
        int color;
        if (isConnected) {
            message = "Good! Connected to Internet";
            color = Color.WHITE;
        } else {
            message = "Sorry! Not connected to internet";
            color = Color.RED;
        }
 
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(findViewById(R.id.fab), message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
 
        View sbView = snackbar.getView();
        TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setTextColor(color);
        snackbar.show();
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
 
        // register connection status listener
        MyApplication.getInstance().setConnectivityListener(this);
    }
 
    /**
     * Callback will be triggered when there is change in
     * network connection
     */
    @Override
    public void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected) {
        showSnack(isConnected);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is all done please read properly what i want to ask, see my output images it is same

Comment: Yes, I understand that what exactly I answered. You just call one method in all activity instead off copy all code

Comment: i want to implement it (without adding in all activities)